# Error in data set firstobs

Tags: sas

I am very, very new to SAS and have been reading stackoverflow questions and SAS documentation, to  write code for a very specific purpose. I have been having a hard time achieving my goal and understanding SAS for two reasons: I can only execute code on a remote server though SSH because I do not have SAS locally (so, on every change, I need to upload the file, execute and get the log and lst files back, check for errors) and most of the introductory topics I have read about are not immediately applicable for my task (I am only interested in using SAS to automate a certain data extraction procedure).

My goal is to:

- read certain tickers (i.e. an identifier for a stock) on a CSV file;
- loop each ticker, retrieving the information I need through certain macros.

So far, I've succeeded in reading the .csv and importing that data to a dataset. To test whether the basics of what I need are working correctly, I made the following code. My goal was, through a loop, to assign the ticker to a certain "variable" currentticker (probably not the right name for it) and print it. The csv file only has two lines it says "IBM" in the first and "DELL" in the other.

```
libname mydir '~/';

data companies;
  infile 'sastests/data/tickers.csv' delimiter=',';
  input ticker $;
run;

proc sql;
 select    count(*)
 into      :OBSCOUNT
 from      companies;
quit;

proc print data=companies;
  var ticker;
run;

%do iter = 1 to &OBSCOUNT;
  data currentticker;
    set companies (firstobs = iter obs = iter);
  run;
  proc print data = currentticker;
  run;
%end;
```

When I go through the log file, I get an error immediately in the firstobs option of data set.

```
Invalid value for the FIRSTOBS option.
```

Why is this so? Shouldn't iter be a number, thus being valid as a FIRSTOBS?

Thank you very much in advance.

Edit 1: Title was not a good description of the problem.

Edit 2: Examples of the macros to be used for a single ticker. Lookup would have to be feeded with &ticker. lookup would be called, then getopt and finally export_tab. This code is not of my authorship, I modified it slightly after it was provided as sample code by WRDS.

```
%macro lookup;

  data idcodes (keep=secid);
  set optionm.secnmd;
  where lowcase(ticker) = &ticker;

  proc sort data=idcodes nodupkey;
    by secid;

  proc print data=idcodes;

%mend;

%macro getopt(year);

  proc sql;
    create table temp as
      select a.* 
      from
        optionm.vsurfd&year as a,
        idcodes as b
      where
        a.secid = b.secid;
  run;

  proc datasets;
    append base=work.&outputfile
    data=work.temp;
  run;

%mend;

%macro export_tab;

  proc export data=&outputfile outfile="&outputfile._out.txt" dbms=tab replace;
  run;

%mend;
```

Comment: What are you actually doing in SAS with this data once you read it in?  If you're just doing the above, SAS is a poor tool for this purpose (perl would be better, python, whatever).  If you're doing something more complicated, odds are there are better ways to do it, if you explain what that is you're doing.

Comment: You could certainly use my approach with that set of macros.  Basically, if the `idcodes` dataset holds ALL of the idcodes for all of the tickers you want, the rest of those will work fine.  Then, when you do the export, you just change the export from using `proc export` to a data step write (like I wrote in my answer) using the `filevar` option and the ticker name in the filename variable.  dlm='09'x if you want tab delimited.

Comment: Just note that you have written: %do iter = 1 to &OBSCOUNT; You actually need to have a percentage in front of the to as well: %do iter = 1 %to &OBSCOUNT;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is basically another answer, so putting it here.  This is how I'd approach the second part - no macros at all . I'm assuming their yearly datasets are sorted by secid already; if not, this might be a bit more complicated, just to avoid the merge then.

```
proc sql;
select quote(ticker) into :tickerlist separated by ',' from companies;
quit;

data idcodes;  *you could also create this by merging optiomn.secnmd to companies by ticker.;
set optionm.secnmd;
where lowcase(ticker) in (&tickers.);
run;

proc sort data=idcodes nodupkey;
by secid;
run;

proc print data=idcodes;
run;

data lotsofyears/view=lotsofyears;
set
optionm.vsurfd2010
optionm.vsurfd2011
optionm.vsurfd2012
optionm.vsurfd2013
;  *or however many you need, you could generate this list if it is long;
by secid;
run;

data mydata;
merge lotsofyears(in=a) idcodes(in=b);
by secid;
filenm=cats("c:\mydir\mydata_",ticker,".dat"); *or secid if that is better;
run;
proc sort data=mydata;
by ticker;
run;
data _null_;
set mydata;
file a filevar=filenm dlm='09'x lrecl=32767;
put (_all_)($); *or perhaps a more complex put statement - see what proc export generates;
run;
```

Comment: Thank you for your thorough and complete answer, you are very helpful. There are certain parts of the code which I do not understand completely, could you help me? Namely:
    Line 3: where lowcase(ticker) in (&tickers.); 
tickers should be a list of tickers, but how do I create it? Through the proc sql as you have in your answer above?

    Line 12: data lotsofyears/view=lotsofyears;

I've seen this type of usage but I don't understand it. What does the slash (/) mean in this context?

Also, I'll read up on data merge because I don't understand it yet.

Comment: Ah, I left the creation of that out - that was in my earlier answer, yes, i'll add it back in.  The view is creating a dataset view - like a sql view, it doesn't actually run through the data, it just stores how you'd like to run through the data, for later use.  That's just how you create it - `data <name> / view <name>`.  `MERGE` is SAS's equivalent of a join, basically.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I still don't get some stuff and I am unable to make it work. I'll post my issues ASAP.

Comment: Hello @Joe. I have been reviewing the code and going step by step to under stand it fully. Thank you again for your help. My issue right now is speed: in the datamerge, when accessing the optionm.vsurfd2013, we are speaking about a file with 130 million observations (or more, I am unsure of the value, will come back to this). Is the merge efficient? Just running the code until the data mydata part and then doing a proc print for the first 20 observations of mydata is taking a while. Given that the macros provided by WRDS use proc sql, would this be more efficient?

Comment: Moreover, when the merge is conducted, it is between lotsofdata and idcodes. But idcodes includes different secids. From what I read about merge, the in=a and in=b should place in a and b zeros and ones, depending on whether a "match" was found in a certain observation or not. When running the last part of the code, file a filevar=filenm, will output each observation with one in a, to the file given by filenm? Will this be efficient given the number of records?

Comment: The merge should be reasonably efficient, as long as you don't need to sort the data - it should be o(n) time (it reads the data through in one pass and writes out what you need in one pass - can't get more efficient than that!).  If it isn't sorted, then there are better options that would still work in one pass - google (or search on SO) for data merging techniques in SAS.  Formats, hash tables, arrays are all reasonable options.

Answer (score 1):

You need to precede the macro variable by `&`, so `firstobs=&iter.`.

However, i'm not sure you really want to do this.  Almost anything you might want to do by macro-iterating over the dataset you can do by regular-iterating over the dataset, and perhaps using BY groups.  Macro iteration is highly inefficient compared to using built-in SAS techniques.

To call a set of code for each line in a dataset, you would do something like this.

```
%macro pulldata(ticker);
data stock_data;
set big_database;
where ticker="&ticker";
file "c:\mydir\myfile_&ticker..csv" dlm=',' lrecl=32767; *double period - first is macro variable delimiter;
put (_all_) ($);
run;
%mend pulldata;

data _null_;
set companies;
call execute('%pulldata(',ticker,')');
run;
```

You also can do something like this, where we use the `filevar` option to allow a dataset to be put out to multiple files (must be sorted by filevar!)

```
proc sql;
select quote(ticker) into :tickerlist separated by ',' from companies;
quit;

data mydata;
set bigdata;
where ticker in (&tickerlist.);
filen = cats('c:\mydata\myfile_',ticker,'.csv');
run;

proc sort data=mydata;
by filen;
run;

data _null_;
set mydata;
file a filevar=filen dlm=',' lrecl=32767;
put (_all_) ($);
run;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am accessing WRDS, a research service that groups several academic databases, and they themselves suggest using SAS. Instead of using the web interface, which does not allow me to do batch data requests, I am seeking to use SAS to automate the data extraction I need. So, the idea is getting a list of stocks for which I want to extract data and then asking for it, one by one (I need separate files). I have successfully used a sample SAS script for one stock and it executed quite quickly, so for my purpose it seems like a good alternative.

Comment: Ah, ok.  So what you probably want to do is to create a dataset with all of your needed files, and then whatever your code is to extract the file from WRDS, put that in a macro, taking parameters like 'stock name' or whatever.  Then use CALL EXECUTE to call that macro. I'll edit a brief explanation into the answer.

Comment: (continuing) The basic idea holds: getting a list of tickers and then executing some macros (yet to be coded) for each one to extract the data I need - which is essentially opening .sas files, doing proc sql to limit the data to what I need, and outputting to a .csv file.

Comment: The general approaches I listed above are probably the better way to go - the second is probably best/most efficient, the former is okay (it is a somewhat more efficient way of doing what you are trying to do).  The data step will happily iterate through itself, you don't need to ask a macro to do it for you.