# Writing dataset to different .csv with specific name using ODS

Tags: csv, sas

Edit 3: Solved. For efficiency purposes, I decided to loop through each secid one at a time, generate a "mydat-like" dataset, export it using proc export. This proved to be a lot more efficient than having mydat with all the data from all secids and then outputing it to different files using ODS. Thank you very much for your help @Joe and @scott, my solution was very much derived from the input of both of you.

Edit 2: By using ods csv I am able to output the different BY groups in my dataset, as long as they are sorted by secid it works well. The filenm field is useless and can be dropped. My issue now is the naming pattern of this solution. The different BY groups are outputted as csv11.csv, csv12.csv... Ideally the program should output the files with each secid.csv, e.g. 106276.csv. Does anybody know how to do this?

```
proc sort data=mydat;
     by secid;
run;

ods csv
    file="/export/csv11.csv"
    newfile=bygroup;
    proc print data=mydat;
        by secid;
    run;
ods csv close;
```

Edit: I am reading up on ODS CSV, as suggested by this page https://communities.sas.com/message/184651, particularly in the solution offered by Cynthia@sas

Original post: Following a former question ([Error in data set firstobs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21050954/error-in-data-set-firstobs)), I have a follow up question.
If I have a data set as the following, how can I output each line to its corresponding filenm?

```
Obs     secid   date        impl_volatility  filenm
131040  106276  31DEC2003   0.24322          /export/mydat_106276.csv
131040  152120  31DEC2003   0.24142          /export/mydat_152120.csv
```

The case here is that I have a dataset with many records with different secids and I have generated the filenm field with the corresponding output file. In the previous question, @Joe had given me a solution for this but I changed the code a bit. Previously, his solution was:

```
data _null_;
    set mydat;
    file a filevar=filenm dlm='09'x lrecl=32767;
    put (_all_)($); 
    *or perhaps a more complex put statement - see what proc export generates;
run;
```

Where a was 1/0 dataset resulting from a data merge, as in (the following code is just an illustration of what a was):

```
data mydat;
    merge mydat1(in=a) mydat2(in=b)
    by secid;
run;
```

But I cannot get this solution to work after the code changes, I no longer have a data merge but rather a proc sql. Either way, I still have filenm in the data set, which should make this feasible.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: I don't see how the PROC SQL affects things.  You just run a data step after the PROC SQL with the filevar statement.

Comment: Hey @Joe. Thank you for your help. I changed to a PROC SQL because I read a reference (which I cannot find on my history...) which stated that generally SQL was quicker. I never fully succeeded in running your code. I was able to print the data but never to output it to the files. Now I am trying to run it, it has been running for 20 minutes using all databases from 96 until 2013, checking two secids (so it is roughly checking 130 million times 18 years, 2340 million records). I was able to run the same request and output it with SQL and ODS export in under 15 minutes, if I recall correctly.

Comment: Any reference which says a SQL join is quicker than a data step merge is incorrect; they're usually identical in speed if it's a 1:1 merge - they're doing the same exact thing.  One or the other may be faster depending on the data.  In your case, since you want to write the files out, data step may well be faster - since SQL will require a second pass to write out the files (it can't write out in same step as merge).

Comment: In any event, my point was regardless of how you merge, you can just use a second datastep after the sql join/merge/whatever to write out the files using the same method as before.

Comment: It is a many to one merge (there are many secids in lotsofyears but only one in idcodes), I believe that was the case analyzed. Ok, so I will try that as well. The code with the merge is yet to finish running.

Comment: Here you have the reference I mentioned, http://www.nesug.org/proceedings/nesug06/dm/da22.pdf (page 6, top table). In fact, it is not merge which is slow, but rather the need for it to have a sorted data set.

Comment: Right, sorting the dataset may make it slower (SQL may still be the same - SQL may either sort the dataset or do a hash merge).  But you can also do a hash 'merge' yourself in the datastep of course.  In your case honestly the hash merge (or formatted merge) in the dataset may be superior to either solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how to do what you want using ods csv, if someone else does, i'll delete this

But, this should create a csv for each secid with the name in your column filenm
  -This won't work if you have multiple rows for one secid

-If you don't want to use the filenm path, change the creation of the macro variable where I commented and change the path to include `.csv`

```
%macro csv_output();

    proc sql noprint;

        create table secid_dim as
        select distinct secid
        from mydat
        ;
    quit;

    data secid_dim;
        set secid_dim;
        id_num + 1;
        by secid;
    run;

    proc sql noprint;

        select distinct max(id_num)
        into :ttl_id
        from secid_dim
        ;
    quit;

    %do ii = 1 %to &ttl_id;
        proc sql noprint;

            select distinct secid
            into :sec_&ii.
            from secid_dim
            where id_num = &ii.
            ;
        quit;

        proc sql noprint;   

            select distinct filenm /*Change to secid if you do not want to use filename, but also change your macro variable call to include .csv*/
            into :file_&ii.
            from mydat
            where secid = &&sec_&ii..
            ;
        quit;

        proc sql noprint;

            create table _tempout_ as
            select *
            from mydat(drop=filenm)
            where secid = &&sec_&ii.
            ;
        quit;

        proc export data=_tempout_ outfile="D:/Scripts&&file_&ii.."
            dbms=csv replace;
        run;

    %end;
%mend;
%csv_output;
```

Comment: Scott, thank you for your help. I do have more than one row for each secid, which, according to what you said, will make the code not work. Even so, I will look into it right now.

Comment: actually, if they have the same filenm it may still work, id have to test it

Comment: yes, if they have the same filenm it will still work, you could also change the filename path to just be the secid, and it should also work